# Remove duplicate using regex jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

I've the below text in a file.

```
10 - Black
10 - Black
10 - Black
10 - Black
10 - Black
20 - Grey/Black
20 - Grey/Black
20 - Grey/Black
20 - Grey/Black
20 - Grey/Black
30 - Blue
30 - Blue
30 - Blue
30 - Blue
30 - Blue
40 - Brown/Red
40 - Brown/Red
40 - Brown/Red
40 - Brown/Red
40 - Brown/Red
```

here i want to replace the following duplicates, but remain the letter below as it is.

In simple i want the output to be as below.

```
10 - Black




20 - Grey/Black




30 - Blue




40 - Brown/Red
```

Here's my regex code: `(\b[^\n,]+)\n(?=.*\b\1\b)`
regex101: https://regex101.com/r/wF0aG1/1

Comment: jquery (javascript) in the browser doesn't have filesysem I/O, so you need to use a different language. Could give you a python script if you want.

Comment: Just use javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT 1**

Try this regex:

```
([^\n].*)\n(?:\1(?:\n|$))*
```

and the substitution:

```
$1\n\n\n
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fV7qA9/5)

Comment: @PhDev , happy to help , also consider accepting answer :)

Answer (score 1):

**Why use regex , when you can use simple JS ?**

After reading the file using jQuery convert the data in file to array and get the unique data from array .

JS

```
    $(document).load('delete.txt', function(data){
         temp = data.split('\n');
         uniqueArray = temp.filter(function (item, pos) {
          return temp.indexOf(item) == pos;
         });
        console.log(uniqueArray);
    });
```

Result in console is
  `["10 - Black\r", "20 - Grey/Black\r", "30 - Blue\r", "40 - Brown/Red\r", "40 - Brown/Red"]`